# Win XP w/SP 3 Will Not Resolve Single IP Address

Tags: windows-xp, dns, proxy

Web host's server took a dump and died. The pulled the drive and swapped to another server. I was on the site when the server died. Now, everyone can see the web site except me. I can go anywhere on the Net. No issues. This one site (mine) I cannot get to through conventional means. Access is possible through a proxy server.

The hosting company is claiming the problem is mine. I've used /flushdns...tried other resolutions...tried unplugging router for period of time...nothing.

Anyone with any clues as to why I can't get to my own site without a proxy yet everyone else can?

Comment: Have you tried to remove all your temp files?

Comment: Have you tried forcing an unexpected reboot of your machine?

Answer (score 0):

Completely remove history temporary files from you PC and use disk cleanup utility to clean temporary file and restart hope this helps you.
and also try registering DNS again

```
     ipconfig /registerdns
```